# How to fix webcam on Cheese

Tags: 16.04, webcam, cheese

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit)
Dell Latitude E5500
Webcam: Creative Notebook Pro (listed as tested and ok for Linux)
Cheese 3.18.1

I installed the webcam and fired up Cheese with 640 x 480 and video was fine until I chose to try "photo" with the Kung Fu effect. At that point the screen went black and I got the message  "There was an error playing video from the webcam". It could have been in photo or video mode when I selected the effect. I have tried unplugging the webcam, restarting Cheese and even re-booting but all I get is 0.5 of a second of video then the same black screen with the same message. The booth screen is stuck on "photo".
I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing Cheese; no change.

I have uninstalled Cheese and installed GTK UVC Video Viewer which displays a video window entitled guvcview. But the main title bar for GTK has no menu and nor has the video window. So I have a functioning webcam and video window but I can't do anything with it, such as record pics or video i.e. there are no File, Edit, Settings e.t.c. options that one would expect in a menu.
My question is this: How can I get Cheese or GTK UVC to function properly?

Thanks

Comment: Give Guvcview a try and see how that works I also use cheese with Ubuntu 16.04 with out any poblems

Comment: @RobGoss Could you convert to answer, please?

Comment: Fabby how am I suppose to do that because that option is no available as far as I can see.